# How to set openmpi C compiler when installed with conda?

Tags: c, macos, clang, conda, openmpi

I installed openmpi v4.1.6 (and dependencies) to a clean environment using anaconda conda-forge channel. After installing and attempting to compile, I get the error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Open MPI wrapper compiler was unable to find the specified compiler
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang in your PATH.

Note that this compiler was either specified at configure time or in
one of several possible environment variables.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After some additional digging, `$ mpicc --showme` reveals `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang` has been chosen as the C compiler, except this is the wrong clang version! `$ clang --version` returns

```
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

This can be fixed by exporting the variable `OMPI_CC=clang` or `OMPI_CC=gcc`, although the [openmpi documentation](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#override-wrappers-after-v1.0) seems to strongly discourage this, or at least implies this shouldn't be necessary.

Where is openmpi getting this compiler information from? Why is it linking to a C compiler that no longer exists and can I change this default behavior?

Installing the latest version of openmpi using conda is successful, but links to the wrong C compiler.

```
$ mpicc --showme
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/fargo-workshop/include -I/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/fargo-workshop/include -L/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/fargo-workshop/lib -L/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/fargo-workshop/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/fargo-workshop/lib -lmpi

$ clang --version
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

$ which -a clang
/usr/bin/clang
```

openmpi won't compile and run anything until I change the OMPI_CC variables

```
$ export OMPI_CC=gcc
```

but I need to do this each time I open a new bash profile (plus this is a work around that really shouldn't be necessary imo)

---

EDIT:

Big thank you to Dmitry for helping me through this. I created some test environments, because I've found that installing gfortran from conda-forge solves the issue.

I created three python enviornments, one where I installed only openmpi, one where I first installed clang using conda-forge, and one where I first installed gfortran using conda-forge. The results are below, where I've left off the long installation info from anaconda.

```
(base) $ conda create -n onlympi python
(base) $ conda activate onlympi
(onlympi) $ conda install -c conda-forge openmpi
(onlympi) $ mpicc --showme
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/onlympi/include -I/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/onlympi/include -L/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/onlympi/lib -L/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/onlympi/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/onlympi/lib -lmpi
(onlympi) $ echo $CC

(onlympi) $ which x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang not found
```

```
(base) $ conda create -n clang-first python
(base) $ conda activate clang-first
(clang-first) $ conda install -c conda-forge clang
(clang-first) $ conda install -c conda-forge openmpi
(clang-first) $ mpicc --showme
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/clang-first/include -I/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/clang-first/include -L/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/clang-first/lib -L/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/clang-first/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/clang-first/lib -lmpi
(clang-first) $ echo $CC

(clang-first) $ which x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang not found
```

```
(base) $ conda create -n gfortran-first python
(base) $ conda activate gfortran-first
(gfortran-first) $ conda install -c conda-forge gfortran
(gfortran-first) $ conda install -c conda-forge openmpi
(gfortran-first) $ mpicc --showme
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/gfortran-first/include -I/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/gfortran-first/include -L/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/gfortran-first/lib -L/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/gfortran-first/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/gfortran-first/lib -lmpi
(gfortran-first) $ echo $CC
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
(gfortran-first) $ which x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/gfortran-first/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
```

As you can see, all three enviornments use the same C compiler for openmpi, but only when I install gfortran does this compiler exist in the enviornment.

gfortran has a lot of dependencies that are installed, I'll include them here. Of particular interest are likely the clang packages that are installed with gfortran but no otherwise: `clang_impl_osx-64` and `clang_osx-64`

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge clang
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/clang-first

  added / updated specs:
    - clang


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  clang              conda-forge/osx-64::clang-17.0.6-hac416ee_2
  clang-17           conda-forge/osx-64::clang-17-17.0.6-default_h6b1ee41_2
  icu                conda-forge/osx-64::icu-73.2-hf5e326d_0
  libclang-cpp17     conda-forge/osx-64::libclang-cpp17-17.0.6-default_h6b1ee41_2
  libcxx             conda-forge/osx-64::libcxx-16.0.6-hd57cbcb_0
  libiconv           conda-forge/osx-64::libiconv-1.17-hd75f5a5_2
  libllvm17          conda-forge/osx-64::libllvm17-17.0.6-hbedff68_1
  libxml2            conda-forge/osx-64::libxml2-2.12.4-hc0ae0f7_1
  zstd               conda-forge/osx-64::zstd-1.5.5-h829000d_0
```

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge gfortran
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/gfortran-first

  added / updated specs:
    - gfortran


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  cctools            conda-forge/osx-64::cctools-973.0.1-h5b2de21_15
  cctools_osx-64     conda-forge/osx-64::cctools_osx-64-973.0.1-h031c385_15
  clang              conda-forge/osx-64::clang-17.0.6-hac416ee_2
  clang-17           conda-forge/osx-64::clang-17-17.0.6-default_h6b1ee41_2
  clang_impl_osx-64  conda-forge/osx-64::clang_impl_osx-64-17.0.6-h1af8efd_8
  clang_osx-64       conda-forge/osx-64::clang_osx-64-17.0.6-hb91bd55_8
  clangxx            conda-forge/osx-64::clangxx-17.0.6-default_h6b1ee41_2
  compiler-rt        conda-forge/osx-64::compiler-rt-17.0.6-ha38d28d_1
  compiler-rt_osx-64 conda-forge/noarch::compiler-rt_osx-64-17.0.6-ha38d28d_1
  gfortran           conda-forge/osx-64::gfortran-13.2.0-h2c809b3_1
  gfortran_impl_osx~ conda-forge/osx-64::gfortran_impl_osx-64-13.2.0-h7643cbd_1
  gfortran_osx-64    conda-forge/osx-64::gfortran_osx-64-13.2.0-h18f7dce_1
  gmp                conda-forge/osx-64::gmp-6.3.0-h93d8f39_0
  icu                conda-forge/osx-64::icu-73.2-hf5e326d_0
  isl                conda-forge/osx-64::isl-0.25-hb486fe8_0
  ld64               conda-forge/osx-64::ld64-609-h0a3eb4e_15
  ld64_osx-64        conda-forge/osx-64::ld64_osx-64-609-hd3532be_15
  libclang-cpp17     conda-forge/osx-64::libclang-cpp17-17.0.6-default_h6b1ee41_2
  libcxx             conda-forge/osx-64::libcxx-16.0.6-hd57cbcb_0
  libgfortran        conda-forge/osx-64::libgfortran-5.0.0-13_2_0_h97931a8_1
  libgfortran-devel~ conda-forge/noarch::libgfortran-devel_osx-64-13.2.0-h80d4556_1
  libgfortran5       conda-forge/osx-64::libgfortran5-13.2.0-h2873a65_1
  libiconv           conda-forge/osx-64::libiconv-1.17-hd75f5a5_2
  libllvm17          conda-forge/osx-64::libllvm17-17.0.6-hbedff68_1
  libxml2            conda-forge/osx-64::libxml2-2.12.4-hc0ae0f7_1
  llvm-openmp        conda-forge/osx-64::llvm-openmp-17.0.6-hb6ac08f_0
  llvm-tools         conda-forge/osx-64::llvm-tools-17.0.6-hbedff68_1
  mpc                conda-forge/osx-64::mpc-1.3.1-h81bd1dd_0
  mpfr               conda-forge/osx-64::mpfr-4.2.1-h0c69b56_0
  sigtool            conda-forge/osx-64::sigtool-0.1.3-h88f4db0_0
  tapi               conda-forge/osx-64::tapi-1100.0.11-h9ce4665_0
  zlib               conda-forge/osx-64::zlib-1.2.13-h8a1eda9_5
  zstd               conda-forge/osx-64::zstd-1.5.5-h829000d_0
```

**tl;dr** incase anyone finds themselves here with the same problem: install gfortran. This will make conda set the correct C compiler for the enviornment.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed `openmpi` using Conda from `conda-forge` channel, then the C compiler looks good to me because conda uses its own compilers: under Linux it is `gcc` and under macOS it is `clang`. However, as you can see, their names are more complicated and encode information about the platform (operating system).

For example, I work in Linux and in a conda environment which depends on a C compiler, the actual C compiler is `path-to-the-conda-environment/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc`.

To change the actual C compiler, Conda sets the `CC` environment variable and that's why `openmpcc` points not simply to `clang` in your case but to `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang`. You can check it by executing in the shell command `echo $CC`. `CC` stands for "C compiler" and basically all build tools respect the value of this environment variable if it is set.

The question is, why the actual C compiler cannot be found in `PATH`.

Did you activate the Conda environment in which `openmpi` is installed?

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is interesting. In my base enviornment, I have a bunch of `conda-dir/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-*` files, but no `conda-dir/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang`. `echo $CC` returns nothing. In this new enviornment I do not have any `conda-dir/envs/conda-enviornment/bin/x86_64*` and `echo $CC` returns nothing. I typically use /usr/bin/gcc for c-compiling. Perhaps a conflict there?

Comment: I did find a file: `path-to-conda-env/share/openmpi/mpicc-wrapper-data.txt`. For now I've edited that file to point to a C compiler that works (for me, `/usr/bin/gcc`), although it's curious my conda C compiler is not pointing to the right place.

Comment: What is `conda-dir`? Can you execute `which x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang` and see where the compiler is located? Also, after you activate conda environment, can you print the $PATH (`echo $PATH | tr : "\n"`) and see that the directory from the `which` command is in the `$PATH`?

Comment: `(base) $ which x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang` gives `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang not found`. `(fargo-workshop) $ which x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang` also returns `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang not found`.

Comment: I do have an older environment, `(fargo)`, which gives `(fargo) $ which x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang` returns `/Users/ericvc/opt/anaconda3/envs/fargo/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang`

Comment: OK, what gives `which mpicc` then in these environments? It seems like you have a broken conda environment, and you need to recreate it?

Comment: If `mpicc` is not in the `fargo` conda environment, then I think environment recreation is the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I recreated the environment and mpicc is working correctly now. Something must have gone wrong when I downloaded before. I'll run some tests to try and track down the problem in the future, but for now I have a working enviornment